# Bitnami window not appearing

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, bitnami

I am taking a course on Android developemt.  We are using Amazon Web Servives.  More specifically, we are using Parse, powered by Bitnami.  I am at the point where I want to connect my app.  What is supposed to happen (accourding to the instructor) is that when I connect my instance and click connect after I select "A Java SSH Client directly from my browser (Java required)", I am supposed to get in new window from Bitnami where I can type in commands to get information to connect to my app.  I do not get that.  Bitnami does not appear in a new window and I only get Mindterms, which is not what I need to accomplish my desired task.  I am using a supported browser and I have Java installed.

I cannot post the entire system log, but here is a portion of it.  I don't know if that will help:
Here is part of my system  log

chmod: cannot access '/var/log/pre-start.log': No such file or directory

/opt/bitnami/mongodb/scripts/ctl.sh : mongodb (pid 1795) already running

/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/scripts/ctl.sh : parse (pid 1982) already running

Syntax OK

/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80

Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: password updated successfully

Starting gonit daemon

chmod: cannot access '/var/log/post-start.log': No such file or directory

- Stopping System V runlevel compatibility[74G[ OK ]

Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'modules:final' at Mon, 06 Mar 2017 20:54:52 +0000. Up 132.57 seconds.
ci-info: ++++Authorized keys from /home/bitnami/.ssh/authorized_keys for user bitnami+++++

Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
[32minfo[39m:    Forever stopped process:
[37m   [39m [37muid[39m  [90mcommand[39m                           [90mscript[39m    [37mforever[39m [37mpid[39m  [37mid[39m [35mlogfile[39m                                       [33muptime[39m
[0] MKle [90m/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/.node.bin[39m [90mserver.js[39m 3458    3466    [35m/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/logs/parse.log[39m [33m5:7:18:7.865[39m 
/opt/bitnami/apps/parse/scripts/ctl.sh : parse stopped
/opt/bitnami/mongodb/scripts/ctl.sh : mongodb stopped
haveged: haveged Stopping due to signal 15

Answer (score 1):

In order to login via SSH to your AWS Parse instance, please follow the steps in this guide:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/#how-to-connect-to-the-server-through-ssh

Once you're logged via SSH you will have whole access to every component within the Bitnami Parse Stack.